# setTimeout in while loop crashes my browser

Tags: javascript

I was trying to move an image by adding to its .style.left and all that worked, until I tried to add a while cycle (to add until its left value is 90) and add setTimeout so that the movement is visible. Problem is that the HTML doesn't even load anymore and after a while it asks me to either Stop script or Continue - both of which help nothing and I am forced to kill the browser.

Here's the relevant code:

```
    function sprint(){
    button = parseInt(document.getElementById("azisButton").style.left.split("%")[0]);
    while(button<10){
        setTimeout(function(){
            button++;
            //console.log(button);
        }, 1000);
        //console.log("Tady");
    }
}
```

Why does it happen? Do I get into infinite loop, or something?

EDIT: Is there any way to do it some other, smart way?

Comment: Animation can be done with CSS or a library (jQuery is an option for simple moves, slides, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while construct is a **synchronous** operation. Therefore you're just adding to the heap till the browser runs out of memory. What you need is a self-invoking function.

Best way to imagine this is to think of `setTimeout` as an IOU or debt system. Imaging the task you made with the while loop as a basket. You're job is to write an IOU and place it in the basket as a "to do later" or "do this task when I'm done with the task of the while loop"

So as you iterate over the loop each `setTimeout` becomes a "to do later" IOU and the while loop goes to the next iteration. Since the incrementing task is in one of those "to do later" functions they never get executed because they are waiting for the while loop to finish first. Hence the infinite loop.

To fix this logic you have to break out of the loop all together and make your own loop logic using a self-invoking function:

```
var button = 0;

function next() {
  button++;
  if (button < 10) {
    setTimeout(next, 1000);
  }
}

next();
```

A good way to keep this strait in your head is to interchange the `setTimeout` with a `console.log` in your mind. With a `console.log` you expect the command to return immediately and move on. The function passed into `setTimeout` will wait till the parent function it is defined in to finish before calling the function you passed it. In the example above `next()` is called *after* the parent `next()` finishes.

Comment: Good answer, but this isn't technically recursive since there is only once instance of `next` on the stack at a time.  Not sure if there is a better phrase than `self invoking` though.

Comment: I updated the example to suite the OP's intent: http://jsfiddle.net/sukima/PWpaq/1/

Answer (score 3):

You built an endless loop! `button++` is incremented in your callback, but the callback is only executed when the loop ends, as JavaScript is single threaded.

Answer (score 2):

That is an infinite loop, since Javascript is single-threaded, none of your callbacks execute until the while loop finishes, which never happens, because button isn't incremented until the callbacks execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sprint(){
    button = parseInt(document.getElementById("azisButton").style.left.split("%")[0]);
    if(button > 90){
        // move button code here
        setTimeout(sprint, 1000);
    }
}
```