# javascript - do while loop setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I have read many topics about `setTimeout` but still i have a problem in understanding how can i implement this function to my loop. 
I'll try to show you what I mean.

```
function RandomHit(anyArray)
{    
    var turechange = false;
    do{
        setTimeout(function(){
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
            if(random===0)
            {
                turechange = true;
                console.log(random);
            }
            if(random===1)
            {
                console.log(random);    
            }
        }, 2000);
    }while(!turechange);
}
```

Every time when the loop goes again, i try slow down code for a 2000 ms. But this doesn't work.

Comment: See eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584035/settimeout-in-while-loop-crashes-my-browser, that appears to be essentially the same question

Comment: I am not clear with your question, but you should use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` instead of `loop` and `setTimeout()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a problem with the one threaded nature of JavaScript (at least in this case - there are some exceptions, though).

What actually happens in your code is an endless `while` loop inside, in which plenty of `setTimeout()` functions are queued up. But as your code never actually leaves the `while` loop, those callbacks wont be executed.

One solution would be to trigger the next timeout function inside the `setTimeout()` callback like this:

```
function RandomHit(anyArray) {   

    var turechange = false;

    function timerFct(){
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
      if(random===0)
      {
          turechange = true;
          console.log(random);
      }
      if(random===1)
      {
          console.log(random);    
      }

      if( !turechange ) {
        setTimeout( timerfct, 2000 );
      }
    }

    timerFct();
}
```

An alternative solution would be to use `setIntervall()` and `clearIntervall()`:

```
function RandomHit(anyArray)
{    
    function timerFct(){
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
      if(random===0)
      {
          turechange = true;
          console.log(random);
      }
      if(random===1)
      {
          console.log(random);    
      }

      if( turechange ) {
        clearTimeout( timeoutHandler );
      }
    }
    var turechange = false,
        timeoutHandler = setInterval( timerFct, 2000 );
}
```